# Drupal region with in a region

Tags: drupal, theming, regions

I know all about adding a region on page.tpl.php and even node.tpl.php in Drupal 6. But, I have a special case where I need to add a region within another region.

In my Drupal install I found the region.tpl.php file which looks like the following:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">

<?php print $content; ?>

</div><!-- /.region -->
```

I amended it to output my custom region:

```
<div class="testing <?php print $classes; ?>">

<?php print $content; ?>

<?php if ($inner_sidebar_right): ?>
    inside inner-sidebar-right
  <div class="inner-sidebar-right"><?php print $inner_sidebar_right; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It doesn't work.

ps: When adding regions in node.tpl.php you have to manipulate _preprocess_node in template.php.
Is there perhaps a _preprocess_region function to help accomplish this?

Comment: i think the template name should be **block-[region].tpl.php** like _block-header.tpl.php_, and their preprocess function __preprocess_block_

Comment: It seems _preprocess_block will works on the block not the region that contains the block ???

Comment: Perhaps, you should provide more information on your "special case". Blocks live within regions. Regions don't live within regions and if they do, it's a hack. It sounds like you just need to simplify your layout or consider something like Panels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [drupal_get_region_content()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_region_content/7) to load the content for any region. So you could theoretically add the following line of code at the beginning of your template for the desired result:

```
<?php $inner_sidebar_right = drupal_get_region_content('inner_sidebar_right'); ?>
```

However, as mentioned in the comments to your original post, I would not recommend this as an ideal solution. Depending on your end goal, there is most likely a more graceful way to accomplish this.